# Grepping through huge files

Tags: grep

I would like to use grep to filter a file B according to a list of elements in A (one element per line). My goal is to keep those lines of B that appear in list A. Both files are ordered.

I am using something like this:

```
grep -f A B
```

The trouble is that file B is several million lines long and file A contains more over a million elements.

Is this the fastest way to go or are there more efficient options out there?

Thanks

Comment: Does it have to be grep?  It might be worth while to sort your stuff into grep and non-grep strings.  String searches being x15 faster or so when done from C# at least.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the promt reply. I have no experience with C# - grep is what we were tought at the MSc course for bioinformatcs...

Comment: So then, have you attempted to run this at all?  it could be that it is fast enough already,  If it is slow, then I would ask about how many of your strings need grep info and how many are just bare string searches?

Comment: no, I haven't tried it yet. I am running my analysis on a cluster and I am a bit concerned about overloading the system. But what you just said is quite reassuring, so I'll try it and get back to you tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`fgrep` or `grep -F` would be faster (`f/F` for `fast`) if you're searching for strings instead of regexps. If both files have whole lines and since they are "ordered", you might even do better running `comm` or `diff` on them.